# Framer Motion: When an element exits it briefly flashes in the centre of the screen despite keys

Tags: framer-motion

I'm trying to have an element animate smoothly in and out as it gets removed from the DOM. Entering is working well, but when I animate the exit, the element briefly flashes out of position.

I thought this may be a key problem, but I've added them to all elements involved.

Sandbox Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-snow-6n8x7f?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-76681841-c6zy4p)

The main thing is that you had `mode="popLayout"` which removes the element from the page layout, basically you can imagine that it makes it as "position: absolute". But I also fixed some other stuff, like removed useless props (keys, layout), added correct height animation (I think you wanted it?), fixed `p` margins (they don't work very well with animations).

So yes, just remove `mode="popLayout"` and adjust the rest.

Comment: Amazing! This works super well! Thanks so much! Originally I was using popLayout because I didn't want to animate the height, I was hoping to have a smooth animate in where the other elements moved out of the way, and the new element just fades in. Is that relatively possible?

Comment: I mean, yes, maybe you can actually do it with `layout` then. A lot of things possible with framer, and sometimes you can get the same effect with different ways.